# Insert OD output in another file

Tags: python, binary, od

I have output from an od command (without access to the original file). Is it possible for me to get the binary data and insert it into another file with a programming language, like python?

Here is the command and output:

```
od -c IUSZ43_KWBC_081935_59763868.bufr
0000000 001  \r  \r  \n   8   6   8      \r  \r  \n   I   U   S   Z   4
0000020   3       K   W   B   C       0   8   1   9   3   5  \r  \r  \n
0000040   B   U   F   R  \0  \0 366 003  \0  \0 022  \0  \0  \b  \0  \0
0000060 002  \0  \r  \0 022  \b  \b  \f  \0  \0  \0  \0   &  \0  \0 001
0000100 200 301 001 002  \v 002  \f 301  \v 301  \f 301 030   A  \r 303
```

I have for edit control over the new file that this data will be appended to. But to reiterate I do not have access to the IUSZ43_KWBC_081935_59763868.bufr file.

Comment: Is your question “How do I convert the output of `od` back into a copy of the input file?”?

Comment: Essentially, in this case, I only need to put the first 40 bytes into the beginning of another fie.

Comment: Is that a “Yes”?

Comment: Yes, I think that will get me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a start

```
echo -e $(cut -d " " -f2- od-out | sed -r -e 's/([0-9]{3})/\\0\1/g' | tr -d " \n")
```

However it is fooled by the spaces (I have not worked out how to distinguish between spaces and field separators), and the 16bit characters, so needs a little work.